# Sending and receiving objects via pubnub

Tags: java, pubnub

I have a Java class called `Transaction`:

```
public class Transaction{

    public Map<String,Double> OutputMap;
    public Input input;
    public String id;
   //..so on

}
```

I am using PubNub to send and receive the objects of type `Transaction` but I am facing an issue in Deserialization.

https://support.pubnub.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051973571-What-types-of-data-can-be-sent-as-messages-with-PubNub-

This link says that "PubNub will serialize and deserialize it for you". I am unable to convert the  received message back to `Transaction` object. Please help me do this.

Comment: the key phrase is in the title of that the K article: "can contain any *JSON* serializable data". Your object is not JSON. Create a method in your Transaction class that converts an instance of that object into JSON object and then publish that. PN will serialize (it probably should say URLencode or escape or something like) for you. When you receive the message, you will parse the JSON, and another method in your class (static method or constructor) will create an instance of the Transaction object.

Comment: This is an old sample app but the Message object does what I said above. You may have to make some changes with respect to the JSON parser library being used in this but it should help: https://github.com/pubnub/webinar-android-intro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/intro/android/webinar/pubnub/com/androidintrowebinar/ChatMessage.java

Comment: It's worth looking at the [message callback code](https://github.com/pubnub/webinar-android-intro/blob/master/app/src/main/java/intro/android/webinar/pubnub/com/androidintrowebinar/PubNubService.java#L67), too that receives the message and gives it to the ChatMessage class to parse.  Let me know if this code helps and I will create a more formal answer based on this.

Comment: One last thing... if you are building chat in Android (or Swift, or React) please check out the [new Chat Components](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat/components/android/overview-android) because it does a lot of heavy lifting for you and in a best-practices way. If this is just a college project or side hobby, it might be over-engineered and could also hide the things that you are wanting to learn.

Comment: @CraigConover Thank you for the comments. I used gson to parse it for broadcasting, and deserialized it by converting it into a json object/array and set the fields manually by using json.get("string").

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is an easier and simpler way, like in JavaScript where you just json.stringify for sending and json.parse while receiving.

Comment: well, the problem is in JavaScript, your message IS a JSON object. In your Java app, the Transaction is just a Java Object and not actually JSON. Java doesn't automatically convert/serialize objects into JSON. Java will serialize any Serializable object into a "string" which technically is JSON. IOW, "foo" is JSON. But your Java object is not Serializing when you publish it. You would need to call the `serialize()` method on your object first. To be continued...

Comment: Now, all that said, what confused you was what the PubNub KB article said: "PN will serialize the JSON for you" to paraphrase. But serialize is likely the wrong word to use. It probably should say "urlencode" or "escape" it for you and then undo that for you on message receive. And... this may only be true for the languages/platforms that can do that. For example, C/C++ might not do it for you (not sure, but seems right if I recall). Did that all make sense?

Comment: TL;DR (maybe too late for that) - `Transaction Object != JSON (or GSON) Object`. If you publish a JSON or GSON object, don't serialize or stringify it first. Just publish object. Ah, and you even said, JS has `JSON.stringify` and the point of that KB article is, don't stringify before you publish because PubNub will have to double escape the already escaped JSON string. So just publish the JSON object or if you have a stringified JSON string, then call `JSON.parse` on it first then publish it.